# how to search and take particular text in perl

Tags: perl

I have one folder it contain 'n' number of html files. I'll read the files and take the one line. (i.e) I'll take the `<img />` tag in one array and print the array. Now doesn't print the array. Can you help me. My code is here.

```
use strict;
use File::Basename;
use File::Path;
use File::Copy;
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';

print "Welcome to PERL program\n";

#print "\n\tProcessing...\n";
my $foldername = $ARGV[0];
opendir(DIR,$foldername) or die("Cannot open the input folder for reading\n");
my (@htmlfiles) = grep/\.html?$/i, readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);


@htmlfiles = grep!/(?:index|chapdesc|listdesc|listreview|addform|addform_all|pattern)\.html?$/i,@htmlfiles;
# print "HTML file is @htmlfiles";

my %fileimages;
my $search_for = 'img';
my $htmlstr;
for my $files (@htmlfiles)
{
    if(-e "$foldername\\$files")
    {
        open(HTML, "$foldername\\$files") or die("Cannot open the html files '$files' for reading");
        local undef $/;my $htmlstr=<HTML>;
        close(HTML);
        $fileimages{uc($2)}=[$1,$files] while($htmlstr =~/<img id="([^"]*)" src="\.\/images\/[^t][^\/<>]*\/([^\.]+\.jpg)"/gi);

    }
}
```

In command prompt.

> perl findtext.pl "C:\viji\htmlfiles"

regards, viji

Answer (score 4):

I would like to point out that parsing HTML with regexes is futile. See the epic https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1521179 for *the* answer.

Your regex to extract image tags is quite broken. Instead of using a HTML parser and walking the tree, you search for a string that…

```
/<img id="([^"]*)" src="\.\/images\/[^t][^\/<>]*\/([^\.]+\.jpg)"/gi
```

- begins with `<img`
- after exactly one space, the sequence `id="` is found. The contents of that attribute are captured if it is found, else the match fails. The closing `"` is consumed.
- after exactly one space, the sequence `src="./images/` is found,
- followed by a character that is not `t`. (This allows for `"`, of course).
- This is followed by *any* number of any characters that are not slashes or `<>` characters (This allows for `"`, again),
- followed by a slash.
- now capture this:

  - one or more characters that are not dots
  - followed by the suffix `.jpg`
- after which `"` has to follow immediately.

#### false positives

Here is some data that your regex will match, where it shouldn't:

```
<ImG id="" src="./ImAgEs/s" alt="foo/bar.jpg"
```

So what is the image path you get? `./ImAgEs/s" alt="foo/bar.jpg` may not be what you wanted.

```
<!-- <iMg id="" src="./images/./foobar.jpg" -->
```

Oops, I matched commented content. And the path does not contain a subfolder of `./images`. The `.` folder is completely valid in your regex, but denotes the same folder. I could even use `..`, what would be the folder of your HTML file. Or I could use `./images/./t-rex/image.jpg` what would match a forbidden `t`-folder.

#### false negatives

Here is some data you would want, but that you won't get:

```
<img
  id="you-cant-catch-me"
  src='./images/x/awesome.jpg' />
```

Why? Newlines—but you only allow for single spaces between the parameters. Also, you don't allow for single quotes `'`

```
<img src="./images/x/awesome.jpg" id="you-cant-catch-me" />
```

Why? I now have single spaces, but swapped the arguments. But both these fragments denote the exact same DOM and therefore should be considered equivalent.

#### Conclusion

go to http://www.cpan.org/ and search for `HTML` and `Tree`. Use a module to parse your HTML and walk the tree and extract all matching nodes.

Also, add a `print` statement somewhere. I found a

```
 use Data::Dumper;
 print Dumper \%fileimages;
```

quite enlightening for debug purposes.

Comment: WWW::Mechanize comes also very handy with such tasks, parsing sites, selecting images, links, etc.